Meaning of this sentence: "He has not said what he thinks either side should give up."
He has not said what he thinks either side should give up. BBC
I couldn't understand the second part of this sentence "....what he thinks either side should give up." I don't know if it is me or the author of the text.
I tried to think in many ways but it doesn't make sense to me in any way as a non-native speaker. Either side means one of the sides and should give up refers to suggestion.
Does it mean He has not said what he thinks which one of the sides should give up?

One meaning of 'either' is 'one or the other [of two people or things]'. Cambridge Dictionary

I believe it is what that is causing your confusion here. "He has not indicated [which things, claims, lands] either side should cede."

@TimR, yes exactly that. I now understand it was what that was causing my confusion, and now I undestand the meaning of the sentence perfectly.

Here is the sentence from the article titled "End Ukraine war" (Seven things Trump says he will do as president):

"He has not said what he thinks either side should give up. Democrats say the move would embolden President Vladimir Putin."

Phrase meanings:
either side  refers to the two sides in the conflict (Russia and Ukraine).
should give up means the concessions or compromises Trump believes either Russia or Ukraine should make.
The article also states: "Trump has criticised the tens of billions of dollars spent by the US on supporting Ukraine in its war with Russia - and has pledged to end the conflict.".
Additionally, "Democrats say the move would embolden President Vladimir Putin."
This suggests a potential shift in U.S. policy, where the U.S. would act more like a mediator, aiming to find a middle ground between Russia and Ukraine.
Edit - 1.
Meaning of the quoted sentence:
The preceding sentence ends with - "and has pledged to end the conflict 'within 24 hours' through a negotiated deal."
OP's sentence should be read in combination with this, meaning :  Trump has not revealed his plan or the specific concessions he expects from each side to stop the war within 24 hours.

"Either side should give up". If this is an opinion that people have, and if Trump also thinks "One of the sides should give up", then I would have expected "He has not said what he thinks about either side giving up". Am I wrong in my thinking or did I get the meaning of the sentence wrong?

@Yunus The sentence you have quoted meaning: Meaning of the quoted sentence:
The preceding sentence ends with - "and has pledged to end the conflict 'within 24 hours' through a negotiated deal."
Your sentence should be read in combination with this, meaning :  Trump has not revealed his plan or the specific concessions he expects from each side to stop the war within 24 hours.
